# display or hide special div by the button or other html tag

Tags: pagination

I have this kind of div:

```
<div id="page-1"></div>
<div id="page-2"></div>
<div id="page-3"></div>
<div id="page-4"></div>
<div id="page-5"></div>
<div id="page-6"></div>
```

And I want to use  or  to display or hide these s.
for example,

```
<a href="#" rel="page-1" class="active">1<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-2">2<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-3">3<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-4">4<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-5">5<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-6">6<a>
```

when page-1 is active, display none of all the div, except `<div id="page-1"></div>`
Can anyone give me some idea?

Comment: What language? PHP? JS? Else?

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can do it this way:

```
<style>
    div {display: none}
    div.active {display: block;}
</style>

<div id="page-1" class="active">p1</div>
<div id="page-2">p2</div>
<div id="page-3">p3</div>
<div id="page-4">p4</div>
<div id="page-5">p5</div>
<div id="page-6">p6</div>

<a href="#" rel="page-1" class="active">1<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-2">2<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-3">3<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-4">4<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-5">5<a>
<a href="#" rel="page-6">6<a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uo3vj66s/

Comment: Thank you so much, it works almost, but inside<div id="page-2">p2</div> I have other div, it display none as well, how do I do this part?

Comment: @WeiweiHan: my code was just an example targeting all divs and links. Use classes, or IDs, here is working fiddle using classes. https://jsfiddle.net/uo3vj66s/1/

Comment: It works now. But I have another problem. when I click the links<a></a>, it is in client response. But if I want to add next and previous, it won't be easy. Can I use the javascript to implement?